# Order of memory disposal and GC in C#

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, dispose

What actually happens in C# when:

```
1) A method gets invoked.
2) The method allocates memory (e.g. MemoryStream mm = new MemoryStream()).
3) An exception occurs in the method which is caught by the invoking classes.
```

Does the resource "mm" gets freed by the garbage collector? Is this a security risk (e.g. DoS)?

P.S.: I know it is best practice to explicitely free any allocated resource. That would mean to use the "using"-statement or "try/catch/finally"-block.

Answer (score 11):

> Does the resource "mm" get freed by the garbage collector?

Once it is dead, yes. Eventually the GC will run and free the memory if it is unreferenced.

> Is this a security risk?

Let's be precise in our terminology. An *asset* is something of value: private data, a user's time, and so on.  An *attacker* is someone who wishes to do harm to the asset. A *threat* is the manner in which the attacker could do harm. A *vulnerability* is an aspect of the scenario which could be taken advantage of by the attacker to make good the threat.

To answer your question we need to know:

- What is the asset?
- Who is the attacker?
- What is the threat the attacker poses to the asset?
- What vulnerability can the attacker take advantage of to make good the threat?

Only once you state the answers to those questions can we possibly know whether failure to immediately release a memory buffer upon an exception is a security risk.

For a real-world example, the asset could be my television, the attacker could be a thief, the threat is theft, and the vulnerability is an unlocked second floor window and the ladder in my garage. The ladder and the window are both part of a vulnerability to that threat. However, neither of them are a vulnerability to the threat of, say, arson. You cannot determine the risk of a particular aspect of a situation until you know what the realistic threat is!

> I know it is best practice to explicitly free any allocated resource.

It is good practice to explicitly clean up *unmanaged* resources, like file handles that are controlled by the operating system. Typically you let the garbage collector clean up managed memory.

Comment: Thanks for bringing up the issue of what is or is not a vulnerability in general. That alone is worth +1.

Answer (score 5):

The memory allocated to `mm` does not get removed by the garbage collector until 1) the garbage collector runs and 2) the reference created by `mm` is flagged for garbage collection and 3) the reference is finalized.

Even in exception circumstances, the memory created for `mm` could still stay, particularly if some other object has a reference to `mm`.

Now... is that a security hole? Depends on the situation. Yes, it's entirely possible for a DoS from too much memory being allocated; this is an issue with any system, but it frankly rarely needs to be dealt with unless your code is particularly bad about dangling memory. Sometimes you might want to use a `ValueType` `struct` for transitory values; it all depends on the situation, there's no one right way to do things.

Regarding your PS: in .NET, it's not best practice to explicitly free every allocated resource; it's best practice to explicitly free *unmanaged* resources. Best practice is to let managed resources lie *unless* you find performance issues, at which point you can consider more draconian methods of memory management. Let the GC do its job properly, and in 99 of 100 cases, everything will be fine.

For more information:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985010.aspx

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but I do not entirely agree with the last paragraph. Aside from the `Dispose()` of `MemoryStream` not doing much (no unmanaged resources), since there is no reference to the `MemoryStream`, there is no difference between an exception or a normal exit, and a DoS on such a method would simply invoke the GC more than necessary. I would think that if you have a DoS vulnerability, this is not your biggest issue. Do you agree or do you have a different opinion?

Comment: @Pieter: I apologize that I may be misunderstanding what you're saying, but I'm going to attempt a reply: I agree that you should `Dispose` of a `MemoryStream`; it "flushes" the buffer and closes the stream, preventing any further writing (assuming it was being used for writing). But I think the original asker was only using `MemoryStream` as an example for any allocated memory; it could just have easily been `new Foo` and would have meant the same thing for his question.

Comment: @Pieter (cont): There is, as you say, no difference between an exception and a normal exit, other than program flow, and I agree that if there is a DoS vulnerability, it is likely to lie elsewhere. I think that in most cases, allocating memory during a method call (with `new Anything()`) does not constitute DoS vulnerability, unless your method is particularly bad about allocating a lot of transitory memory. Even then, that's less "DoS vulnerability" and more "sloppy programming".

Comment: I agree if you make it a general case. I like your addition to the answer. +1

Answer (score 1):

you should use thr try/catch/finally structure and call the mm.Disponse() into tye finally block to release all the unmanaged resource. In the case of the memoryStream,  it calls Stream.Dispose(), which in turn will dispose an event created
as a result of calling asynchronous methods (.BeginRead(), .BeginWrite())
if they were not all finished before the stream was finalized

Comment: Although I agree with your suggestions regarding the use of a MemoryStream, I think the MemoryStream in the original post was more of an example; I think @bonobo was wondering about any allocated memory, and it could just as easily have been a `Foo` object that was allocated in step 2.

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to add some clarification about the using statement.

Any object that deals with unmanaged resources (such as File and Font) are supposed to implement the IDisposable interface...  Which is what the [Using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) works with.

The purpose of IDisposable and the Using statement is to ensure that unmanaged resources are properly cleaned up instead of left hanging around once you are done with them.

So, yes, best practice is to implement the Using statement; however, it is not best practice to free "any" allocated resource, just the unmanaged ones.

**Per MS:** "*As a rule, when you use an IDisposable object, you should declare and instantiate it in a using statement.*"